# Azure managed identity for Azure service bus with java sdk

Tags: java, azure, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-managed-identity

How can I send messages to a topic using Azure managed identity in java?
Right now im using the connectionString to send the message to the topic.

```
   ServiceBusSenderClient senderClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
       .connectionString(connectionString)
       .sender()
       .topicName(topicName)
       .buildClient();
```

In the Azure SDK for java, i could only find this example, which is for service bus queue

```
ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient sender = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
           .credential("<<fully-qualified-namespace>>", credential)
           .sender()
           .queueName("<<queue-name>>")
           .buildAsyncClient();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second snippet is mostly correct; you're missing the step of creating the credential that you're passing to the builder.   That is discussed in the [Authorizing with DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/java/api/overview/azure/messaging-servicebus-readme?view=azure-java-stable#authorizing-with-defaultazurecredential) section of the overview and looks like:

```java
TokenCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
    .build();

ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient receiver = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
    .credential("<<fully-qualified-namespace>>", credential)
    .receiver()
    .queueName("<<queue-name>>")
    .buildAsyncClient();
```

Service Bus can use any of the [Azure.Identity credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-java-stable#credential-classes) for authorization. `DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder` is demonstrated only because it is a chained credential that allows for success in a variety of scenarios.  More information can be found in the [Azure.Identity overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/java/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-java-stable#defaultazurecredential).

If you'd prefer to restrict authorization to only a managed identity, you can do so by using `ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder` rather than the default credential.  An example of creating the can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com//java/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-java-stable#authenticating-in-azure-with-managed-identity).  It can then be passed to Service Bus in the same manner as the default credential.